# Jenkins Groovy postbuild script can't access injected environment variables

Tags: build, properties

I'm trying to get a Groovy script that runs as a post-build step in a Jenkins job to access an injected variable but it keeps getting null.

I've kept the job as simple as possible so there are only 2 real bits of configuration to consider.

Here's how the property is injected. I could use other methods but this is intended for a more complicated job that reads in external properties.

[image: Injecting the variable]

This is the Groovy script I have so far. It will do something else with the value once it gets it.

[image: The Groovy post-build script]

This is the logging from running the job.

[image: The build logging]

I'm not a Groovy expert and I've searched and tried a number of things but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course having posted a question I then got the answer myself...

New script:

[image]

New logging:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set the value of the variable in Jenkins and access them in Slack notifications using the below script in Groovy PostBuild:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.EnvVars

manager.listener.logger.println("======Search Log=======");

def total_tests_count=0
def total_pass_count = 0
def total_failed_count = 0
def total_skipped_count=0

def myVar
def envVar
def newEnv 

def matcher = manager.getLogMatcher(".*Tests Summary(.*)\$")

if(matcher?.matches()) {

 //   manager.addShortText(matcher.group(1), "grey", "white", "0px", "white")
    manager.listener.logger.println("matcher-0=== "+matcher.group(0));

    manager.listener.logger.println("matcher-1 ====== "+matcher.group(1));

    int total_start = matcher.group(1).indexOf("Total:")
    total_tests_count = matcher.group(1).split('Total:')[1].split('Passed:')[0]
    manager.listener.logger.println("extracted total_tests_count : ${total_tests_count}")

   // Sets env var for total_tests_count
     TOTAL_TESTS_COUNT=0
     myVar = total_tests_count;
     envVar = new EnvVars([TOTAL_TESTS_COUNT: myVar]);
     newEnv = Environment.create(envVar);
    manager.build.environments.add(0, newEnv);

    int passed_start = matcher.group(1).indexOf("Passed:")
    total_pass_count = matcher.group(1).split('Passed:')[1].split('Failed:')[0]
    manager.listener.logger.println("extracted total_pass_count : ${total_pass_count}")

   // Sets env var for total_pass_count
     TOTAL_PASS_COUNT=0
     myVar = total_pass_count;
     envVar = new EnvVars([TOTAL_PASS_COUNT: myVar]);
     newEnv = Environment.create(envVar);
    manager.build.environments.add(1, newEnv);


    int failed_start = matcher.group(1).indexOf("Failed:")
    total_failed_count = matcher.group(1).split('Failed:')[1].split('Skipped:')[0]
    manager.listener.logger.println("extracted total_failed_count : ${total_failed_count}" )

   // Sets env var for total_failed_count
     TOTAL_FAILED_COUNT=0
     myVar = total_failed_count;
     envVar = new EnvVars([TOTAL_FAILED_COUNT: myVar]);
     newEnv = Environment.create(envVar);
    manager.build.environments.add(2, newEnv);

    int skipped_start = matcher.group(1).indexOf("Skipped:")
    total_skipped_count = matcher.group(1).split('Skipped:')[1]
    manager.listener.logger.println("extracted total_skipped_count : ${total_skipped_count}")

   // Sets env var for total_skipped_count
     TOTAL_SKIPPED_COUNT=0
     myVar = total_skipped_count;
     envVar = new EnvVars([TOTAL_SKIPPED_COUNT: myVar]);
     newEnv = Environment.create(envVar);
    manager.build.environments.add(3, newEnv);

}
```

In Jenkins, I was able to access using custom message:

> Please check below url for test automation output for PR build
> Total Cases: $TOTAL_TESTS_COUNT, Passed:$TOTAL_PASS_COUNT, Failed: $TOTAL_FAILED_COUNT, Skipped: $TOTAL_SKIPPED_COUNT.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).